# Transpose list in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-scriptler

I want to transpose this list in a groovy script.
There are two lists

**result_name = ["API (example)","Management Portal (example)","Component1","Component2",]**

**result_ids = ["3wrhs4vp3sp5","g2828br1gzw9","68pnwhltxcq0","fy8g2nvvdg15",]**

I am expecting an output like list[0][0], list[1][1]....
example:

```
API (example) 3wrhs4vp3sp5
Management Portal g2828br1gzw9
Component1 68pnwhltxcq0
Component2 fy8g2nvvdg15
```

I am trying this using

> def result = [[result_name], [result_ids]].transpose()

but the result is:

> Result: [[["API (example)","Management Portal (example)","Component1","Component2",], ["3wrhs4vp3sp5","g2828br1gzw9","68pnwhltxcq0","fy8g2nvvdg15",]]]

EDIT: Updated sample code in the question:

```
proc1 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "curl https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/lbh0g6b5mwnf/components?api_key=<key>"].execute()
proc2 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "grep -Po '\"name\": *\\K\"[^\"]*\"'| tr '\n' ', '"].execute()
proc3 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "curl https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/lbh0g6b5mwnf/components?api_key=<key>"].execute()
proc4 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "grep -Po '\"id\": *\\K\"[^\"]*\"'| tr '\n' ', '"].execute()

all_name = proc1 | proc2
all_ids = proc3 | proc4
def result_name = [all_name.text]
def result_ids = [all_ids.text]

println result_name
println result_ids

def result = [result_name, result_ids].transpose()
```

**Result**

```
["API (example)","Management Portal (example)","Component1","Component2",]
["3wrhs4vp3sp5","g2828br1gzw9","68pnwhltxcq0","fy8g2nvvdg15",]
Result: [["API (example)","Management Portal (example)","Component1","Component2",, "3wrhs4vp3sp5","g2828br1gzw9","68pnwhltxcq0","fy8g2nvvdg15",]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

After a few debugging, I realized that my list is having a single string and because of that split() was not expecting that weird input. I was able to print the first String by putting in `newstr` and then split(',') code below:

```
all_name = proc1 | proc2
all_ids = proc3 | proc4
    
result_name = [all_name.text]
result_ids = [all_ids.text]

newstr = result_name[0]
result_newstr = newstr.split(',')

newids = result_ids[0]
result_newids = newids.split(',')

def aa = []
for(int i = 0;i< result_newstr.size(); i++) {
    a = result_newstr[i].concat(" ").concat(result_newids[i])
  aa.add(a)
}
return aa
```

This results:

```
"API (example)" "3wrhs4vp3sp5"
"Management Portal (example)" "g2828br1gzw9"
"Component1" "68pnwhltxcq0"
"Component2" "fy8g2nvvdg15"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code sample you show, you wrapped both `result_name` and `result_ids` lists into the additional lists. Rewrite the following code:

```java
def result = [[result_name], [result_ids]].transpose()
```

to:

```java
def result = [result_name, result_ids].transpose()
```

and you will get the expected result.

Comment: I have tried both ways it did not work!
I have updated my code in the update section of the question.

Comment: You posted the api keys in your question. Revoke them until someone starts using them without your permission.

Comment: Aside from that, it looks like the following code `def result_name = [all_name.text]` produces a list of a single element which is a string representation of a list. If you want to use the `transpose` method as explained, you need to make sure that the `result_name` and `result_ids` are lists of multiple strings. Something like `all_name.text.split(',(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)')*.replaceAll('"','')` to split by `,` outside doublequotes.

Comment: Thanks Removed API_KEY(Though it was temporary), Now this invokes some errors ```java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
 at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140) org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
 at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:11)```